# How can I only upload text files using drag and drop java script

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Hello I am trying to upload files using drag and dropbox and I want to be able to only upload text files no pictures, shortcuts etc. how can I do this as right now my code does do the opposite which is show a image submit as a thumbnail.
This is my js code now :

```
    const dropZoneElement = inputElement.closest(".drop-zone");

    dropZoneElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        inputElement.click();
    });

    inputElement.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        if (inputElement.files.length) {
            updateThumbnail(dropZoneElement, inputElement.files[0]);
        }
    });

    dropZoneElement.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dropZoneElement.classList.add("drop-zone--over");
    });

    ["dragleave", "dragend"].forEach((type) => {
        dropZoneElement.addEventListener(type, (e) => {
            dropZoneElement.classList.remove("drop-zone--over");
        });
    });

    dropZoneElement.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (e.dataTransfer.files.length) {
            inputElement.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
            updateThumbnail(dropZoneElement, e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
        }

        dropZoneElement.classList.remove("drop-zone--over");
    });
});


function updateThumbnail(dropZoneElement, file) {
    let thumbnailElement = dropZoneElement.querySelector(".drop-zone__thumb");

    
    if (dropZoneElement.querySelector(".drop-zone__prompt")) {
        dropZoneElement.querySelector(".drop-zone__prompt").remove();
    }

    
    if (!thumbnailElement) {
        thumbnailElement = document.createElement("div");
        thumbnailElement.classList.add("drop-zone__thumb");
        dropZoneElement.appendChild(thumbnailElement);
    }

    thumbnailElement.dataset.label = file.name;


    if (file.type.startsWith("text/")) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => {
            thumbnailElement.style.backgroundImage = `url('${reader.result}')`;
        };
    } else {
        thumbnailElement.style.backgroundImage = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a working example.

Comment: Have you consider adding a `accept` attribute to your file input?

Answer (score 0):

Just check file type with something like this:

```
if (e.dataTransfer.files[0].type == "text/plain")
{
  //accept file
}
```